# Installing php 7.0 on amazon linux 2

Tags: php, packer, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to create an Amazon Linux 2 AMI image using packer with php 7.0 installed, since that's the version we have currently in our production machine. Now, php 7.0 has reached end of life status, so you can't find it on the normal repositories, not even amazon-linux-extras. I've resorted to using Remi's repositories, installing php70, but my issue is that, even if I put `scl enable php70 bash` in my template, on the running instance I doesn't seem to register it as the default php version. To be more clear, my template has a provisioner block like this:

```
{
            "type": "shell",
            "inline":[
                "sudo yum install -y http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm",
                "sudo yum install -y yum-utils",
                "sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70",
                "sudo yum update -y",
                "sudo yum install -y php70",
                "sudo scl enable php70 bash"
            ]
}
```

How can I install php 7.0 properly, and what should I do for installing extensions?

Answer (score -1):

For a proper installation, simply follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

In short, you don't need the php70-php* packages (SCL) but the php-* packages, read the [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl).